# Is there an issue with the Anylogic Agent to fluid block?

Tags: anylogic, agent

I'm trying to model a mixing system where fluid batches come form both fluid sources and agents converted into fluids by the "agent to fluid" block, but anytime I connect the "agent to fluid" block to any tank or sink I get an error and the model won't load. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong or if there's an issue in the program? I haven't done anything with the java code yet, and haven't changed any properties of the agent either. Everything works just fine if the block is removed or ignored.

This is my error:
java.lang.RuntimeException: root:
tank239 (StorageTank) : This markup element is already connected with some data source:                    root.agentToFluid - AgentToFluid
in count = 0
out: Rate = 0 cubic meters / s
Amount passed = 0 cubic meters
Priority = -1
Desired output rate = 1 cubic meters / s
Contains fluid: 0 cubic meters

```
    at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.error(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Agent.error(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Utilities.error(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.markup.MarkupShape.h(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.markup.AbstractFluidMarkup.setDataSource(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.fluid.AgentToFluid.onStartup(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Agent.j(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Agent.j(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Agent.start(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.start(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.ExperimentSimulation.m(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.ExperimentSimulation.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.ExperimentSimulation.l(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.internal.b$b.run(Unknown Source)
```

I've tried all of the standard IT standbys, I removed the block and replaced it, shut down the whole application and closed the model, rebuilt it from scratch and have already looked through the tutorials and blog posts on their website.

I just want to convert a generic agent into a batch of fluid, so it can be mixed with my other fluids. I thought the block would do exactly that, but thus far I have not seen it work once.

Comment: Can you re-phrase this into a minimum viable problem, so we can _easily_ recreate it? (i.e. it takes less than 2 mins to do). Happy to help but this is rather long-winded :)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I figured it out on my own, My issue was that I had the Agent connected in the flowchart, and also had a tank display selected in the block itself. I don't know why, but that caused the error.